# Why does input redirection work differently when in command substitution?

Tags: bash, shell, file, redirect, command-substitution

Consider the following case:

```
$ echo "abc" > file
$ var=$(< file)
$ echo "$var"
abc
```

Inside the command substitution, we use a redirect and a file, and the content of the file is correctly captured by the variable.

However, all the following examples produce no output:

```
$ < file
$ < file | cat
$ < file > file2
$ cat file2
```

In all these cases the content of the command is not redirected to the output.

So why is there a difference when the redirect is placed inside the command substitution or not? Does the redirect have a different function when inside vs outside a command substitution block?

Comment: You should be using `cat <file`

Comment: @anubhava: That's true. Or even `cat file`. The thing I don't understand though is the reason behind the different syntax. Why does `$(<file)` (without `cat`) work?

Comment: In `<file`, you're redirecting content of file on stdin of nothing. `$(< file)` is just a BASH specific faster shortcut for `$(cat file)`

Comment: @anubhava: I see, so the `< file` syntax is only valid inside the command substitution. I thought that the command inside or outside would follow the same rules.

Comment: try `< file wc` or `< file grep -o 'b'`

Comment: @Sundeep: Both of these examples work. But the difference is that they involve executing a command, whereas in `$( < file )` the redirect works even with no command.

Comment: I think that is how redirection works outside of substitution.. it needs a command which can accept it as stdin

Comment: Technically, `$(< file)` is not a redirection; it's a special case of command substitution that *looks* like a redirection.

Comment: @chepner: I think your comment qualifies as an answer... So basically if I understand correctly, you are saying that since it is not really a redirect, but a special case of command substitution, we should not expect the syntax to work anywhere a command is expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(< file)` is not a redirection; it is just a special case of a command substitution that uses the same syntax as an input redirection.

In general, an input redirection must be associated with a command. There is one case that arguably could be considered an exception, which is

```
$ > file
```

It's not technically a redirection, since nothing is redirected *to* the file, but `file` is still *opened* in write mode, which truncates it to 0 bytes.